# How to update Text with property observers in ContentView when input variable is changed

Tags: properties, textview, swift5, xcode11, observers

**Using XCode 11.4, Swift 5.0**

I would like to have the Text variable (`correctionLabel`) in the ContentView be updated whenever a variable I have created (stored in app's user defaults) is changed. The code below shows my attempt to use `didSet` to update the Text in ContentView whenever the input variable is changed:

```
//ContentView.swift
//this is a single page application


import SwiftUI

let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

var correctionLabel = Text("O")
var corrections = defaults.integer(forKey: "CorrectionCount") {
    didSet {
        correctionLabel = Text("\(corrections)")
        print("old value is \(oldValue) and new value is \(corrections)")
        print(correctionLabel)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        correctionLabel

    }
}

//code for incrementing the corrections variable not shown here
```

Everything else with the app has been tested and works, verifying with `print()` tests to ensure the `corrections` variable is indeed increasing when iPhone orientation is changed.
However, the on-screen counter starts at 0 but never increases, and the console shows this error for `print(correctionLabel)`:

```
Text(storage: SwiftUI.Text.Storage.anyTextStorage(SwiftUI.(unknown context at $1cf871518).LocalizedTextStorage), modifiers: [])
```

I feel that the issue must be something minor and I am missing something here, since the desired end product is a simple on-screen counter that starts at 0 and increases by 1 incrementally. Any insight is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I used the implementation of @EnvironmentObject which is new to SwiftUI,
see a nice tutorial here: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

if you are using a function within a class like I was to update your variable (in this case it was the correction variable) make sure you are referencing the same instance of the class function, instead of calling a new instance of the class function!